Sprig: write number of loaded entries into the url with sprig
I am working on a nested component where you can filter entries and also load more with a button click.
I want to write the number of curently loaded entries into the url so I that when you navigate to an entry and come back, it loads the entries that you loaded before again.
My struggle is that when I click on the button at the moment, it writes always 4 less than it should.
Don't know where the error is at my current template / thinking process.
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}
{% set limit = limit ?? 4 %}
{% set loaded = loaded|default(false) %}
{% set teaserEntries = teaserEntries|default([]) %}
{% set teaserEntryQuery = craft.entries.section('projects') %}
{% set matchingFunctionId = matchingFunctionId|default(0) %}
{% set matchingFunction =
    craft.entries.id(matchingFunctionId).one()|default(null)
%}

{% set pushUrl = '?offset=' ~ (4 + offset) %}

{% if matchingFunction %}
    {% set relatedEntries =
        teaserEntryQuery.relatedTo({
            targetElement: matchingFunction
        })
    %}

    {% set pushUrl = matchingFunction.section.handle != 'services'
        ? '/' ~ matchingFunction.uri ~ '?offset=' ~ (offset + limit)
        : '/projekte/leistungen/' ~ matchingFunction.slug ~ '?offset='
            ~ (offset + limit)
    %}
{% else %}
    {% set relatedEntries = teaserEntryQuery.offset(0 + limit).limit(offset) %}
{% endif %}

{% set customButtonAttributes %}
    sprig s-val:offset="{{ offset + limit }}" s-val:loaded="true"
    s-swap="outerHTML" s-target="this" s-push-url={{ pushUrl }}
{% endset %}

{% if loaded %}
    {% set teaserEntries = relatedEntries.offset(offset).limit(limit).all() %}
{% else %}
    {% set teaserEntries = offset > 0
        ? relatedEntries.limit(offset).all()
        : relatedEntries.limit(limit).all()
    %}
{% endif %}

{% set totalEntries = teaserEntryQuery.count() %}

{% if teaserEntries %}
    {% include 'components/modules/teaser/teaser-layout/teaser-layout' with {
        teaserEntries: teaserEntries,
        format: 'fourElements',
        classStringModifiers: 'page-projects-overview__teaser',
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
    } %}
{% endif %}

{% if offset + limit < totalEntries %}
    {% include 'components/basic/button/button.twig' with {
        label: 'project.overview.button.label'|t,
        customClass: 'page-projects-overview__button',
        customAttributes: customButtonAttributes|raw
    } only %}
{% endif %}

